# Removing an unreasonable number of curses

Tags: pathfinder-1e, polymorph, curses

So, in my last session, my trusty Dwarf Fighter became cursed. He is currently afflicted with *one hundred distinct polymorph curses*. For both my sake and the DM's, how would he go about getting himself back to normal? If he purchased the use of a Remove Curse spell, would it remove all of them?

The current ruling is that I'd get another roll on the reincarnation table for each iteration of Remove Curse, but I wanted to get a second (or third/fourth/fith/etc opinion).

Comment: Please, for the sake of our collective sanity, explain how he managed to get that many curses in a single session.  I won't be able to sleep until I know.

Answer (score 34):

From the text from the Remove Curse spell, emphasis mine:

> Remove curse can remove ***all*** curses on an object or a creature.

So barring DM Fiat, you should be fine purchasing one casting of the Remove Curse spell, provided the person you buy the spell from can meet the DC for the curse removal by caster level check about one hundred times. To completely remove all of the curses, you may have to have multiple castings on hand.

Each Remove Curse roll consists of a caster level check against the DC of that particular curse, so each time the spell is cast, a caster level check has to be rolled 100 times to determine exactly how many of the curses are removed.

Comment: Although, of course, if you can guarantee that the CL is always sufficient to hit the DC on a 1, no actual rolls are needed.

Comment: Finally, a situation where one of those digital dice rolling apps sounds pretty useful!

Comment: If you collect all the d20s around the table it's only probably 5 to 10 rolls. Not that bad. (Comparing to a full attack of a hasted two-weapon fighting lvl20 fighter with blind-fight against a concealed foe).

Comment: Another option, as a shorthand, would be to roll only 2-3 times, and state that the spell removes all of the curses that would have been removed by the best of those rolls. This keeps the number of rolls manageable, yields a high likelihood that the first casting will still remove *most* of the curses, while still having a chance that unless all of the curses were weak, a couple of castings *might* be required.

Comment: As a (lazy) DM, I'd probably calculate the percentage to fail DC, and say that many curses remain. Once the number of remaining curses fell below my dice threshold for massive rolls, then I'd break out the dice and finish it up.

Answer (score 14):

The [Baleful Polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/baleful-polymorph) spell says: "Any polymorph effects on the target are automatically dispelled when a target fails to resist the effects of baleful polymorph."

This does bring up an interesting question about how someone managed to give you a hundred "polymorph curses".  I guess that's using a different mechanic than Baleful Polymorph?

Anyway, technically if you get someone to Baleful Polymorph you and then dispel their own spell, that should get rid of all polymorph effects without requiring 100 dispel checks.

Comment: +1 And then you just need to remove the baleful polymorph, somehow...